# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object Error

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

```
    cq.multiselect(selected_columns);
    cq.where(final_selection);

    List<Object[]> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

    List<Map<String,Object>> final_result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < result.size() ; i++)
    {
        Map<String,Object> temp = new HashMap<>();

        for(int j = 0 ; j < result.get(i).length ; j++)
            temp.put("student_"+selected.get(j), result.get(i)[j]);

        final_result.add(temp);
    }
```

when length of Object array inside of result list is 1 then this **result.get(i).length** generates this error **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object**

selected columns list consist of column names which I need to select.
can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you select a single item, you just get that item. it is not embedded within an array of size 1.